# Matrices whose Linear Combinations are All Singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to know if the following problem of elementary linear algebra is already solved / solvable.

For two (singular) $n\times n$ matrices $P$ and $Q$, if $\det(\lambda P+\mu Q)=0$ for any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, what are conditions on $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: This is obviously the case if either all columns of the two matrices taken together are contained in some hyperplane, or the corresponding situation holds for all rows taken together. I'm not sure whether there are other possiblilties.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : Consider e.g. $A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr}$, $B = \pmatrix{0 & 5 & 5\cr -1 & -5 & 0\cr 
1 & 12 & 7\cr}$

Comment: I think that a possible strategy in tackling this problem is to take certain $\lambda_1,\mu_1,\lambda_2,\mu_2$ satisfying $\begin{vmatrix}\lambda_1&\mu_1\\ \lambda_2&\mu_2\end{vmatrix}\neq0$ so that we can take $(\lambda_1P+\mu_1Q,\lambda_2P+\mu_2Q)$ as the new base instead of $(P,Q)$. By doing so we may assume certain special properties on $P$ and $Q$. As a (rather weak) example, we can make the top left corner of $P$ and bottom right corner of $Q$ become zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, just some sufficient and some necessary conditions.

Let's look at the opposite condition. Fix $u,v\in\mathrm{End}_k(V)$ two singular (non proportional) endomorphisms of the finite dimensional $k$-vector space $V$: what conditions are necessary or sufficient for there to be a scalar $\lambda$ such that $u+\lambda v\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$?

The following conditions are necessary:

1. $\mathrm{Ker}(u)\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(v)$;
2. $\mathrm{Im}(u)+\mathrm{Im}(u)=V$;
3. $v\big(\mathrm{Ker}(u)\big)\oplus u\big(\mathrm{Ker}(v)\big)$.

The first is @chaochuang's answer, and the second is @Marc van Leeuwen' comment. To see the necessity of the third condition, write down matrices in a basis adapted to $V=\mathrm{Ker}(u)\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(v)\oplus S$.
The following conditions are sufficient (at least when $k$ is big enough, for instance if $\mathbb Q\subset k$):

1. The induced morphism $\tilde{v}:\mathrm{Ker}(u)\rightarrow V\rightarrow V/\mathrm{Im}(u)$ is an isomorphism i.e. $v(\mathrm{Ker}(u))\oplus\mathrm{Im}(u)$;
2. The induced morphism $\tilde{u}:\mathrm{Ker}(v)\rightarrow V\rightarrow V/\mathrm{Im}(v)$ is an isomorphism i.e. $u(\mathrm{Ker}(v))\oplus\mathrm{Im}(v)$.

To see the sufficiency of the first point, write down the matrix for $u+\lambda v$ where the initial base of $V$ is adapted to $S\oplus \mathrm{Ker}(u)=V$, and the final base is the images under $u$ of the basis vectors chosen in $S$ and the images  under $v$ of the basis vectors in $\mathrm{Ker}(u)$, and let $\lambda\rightarrow 0$: the determinant of this matrix is a polynomial in $\lambda$ of the form $\lambda^d(1+\cdots)$ where $d=\dim~\mathrm{Ker}(u)$.

Going back to the initial problem, we get $3$ sufficient conditions for the span of $u$ and $v$ to be completely singular, and $2$ necessary conditions.

Comment: I've never seen $A \oplus B$ used by itself as a condition before. What does it mean?

Comment: @EricStucky It's a shorthand for "$A\oplus B$ makes sense", which is a longhand for $A\cap B=\{0\}$. It makes sense if you think of a programming language in which the procedure "Take Direct Sum" returns *False* if it encountered an error, and returns a truth-y value otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient condition is $P$ and $Q$ share at least one eigenvector for 0 eigenvalue:

$P\mathbf{v}= 0 \mathbf{v}$, $Q\mathbf{v}= 0 \mathbf{v}$

so for any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $(\lambda P+\mu Q) \mathbf{v} = 0 \mathbf{v}$, which means 0 is still an eigenvalue of $\lambda P+\mu Q$, i.e. $\det(\lambda P+\mu Q)=0$.

I doubt it's also a necessary condition.

Comment: It is not necessary, take $P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $Q = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. The kernels are orthogonal, but the above property holds.

Answer (score 0):

For matrices $P, Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, the following is a degree-$n$ polynomial:
$$\det(\lambda P + (1-\lambda) Q) = \det(Q + \lambda (P-Q)) = \sum_{i=0}^n \xi_k(P, Q) \cdot \lambda^k$$
Therefore the following is the desired criterion for the determinant to vanish identically:
$$ \text{For all } k \in \{0,1,  \ldots n\}, \quad \xi_k(P, Q) = 0$$
The quantities $\xi_k$ are directly computed to be:
$$ \xi_k(P, Q) = \sum_{\alpha \in \{0, 1\}^n \\ \sum_i \alpha_i = k} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod_{i=1}^n \bigg[ \alpha_i P_{i, \sigma(i)}+ (1-2\alpha_i) Q_{i, \sigma(i)}  \bigg]$$
Note that each $\xi_k(P, Q)$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial in the entries of $P$ and $Q$.

Therefore, the collection of all $(P, Q) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$ whose linear combinations are all singular lies on an **algebraic variety** defined by $(n+1)$ polynomial equations of degree $n$. Note that its degree of freedom is at least $2n^2 - n - 1$.

(I'm the same person who posted the question, just 10 years into the future, after finishing PhD in math!)