# When is every matrix in the span of two matrices singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two square matrices $A, B$, when is
$$\det(A+tB) = 0$$
for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$?

An easy sufficient condition is that $A$ and $B$'s kernels have nontrivial intersection. Per Henning's comment below, this is not also necessary.  Does there exist a nice necessary and sufficient characterization?

Comment: No, consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good example, thanks.

Comment: Related: It's not very hard to show that $A+tB$ is invertible for every real $t$ if and only if $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}B$ doesn't have any nonzero, real eigenvalues.

Comment: Also, Henning Makholm's example suggests another easy sufficient condition. Namely: if the column spaces $C(A)$ and $C(B)$ do not together span the whole space, then $A+tB$ is always singular.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/173026